# Using text index to search for substring of a word in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document as shown below in a MongoDB collection which has text index on "key1".

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "key1": "this is the sentence",
    "key2": "some other sentence"
}
```

I was trying below query to find this record.

```
db.collectionname.find({ $text: { $search: "enten" } })
```

Here, "enten" is substring of word "sentence". I tried above query but it doesn't return this document.

Is there a way I could make search via substring of a word work with text index?

I know we can use a regular index on key1 and do regex search query but it seems to scan all index values of key1, which seems to be on par with full collection scan.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Using `$regex` would cause more harm than good. What you are looking for is called a `nGram Search`. MongoDB text indexes do not support it at the moment.

Had you been deployed on MongoDB Atlas platform, you could have used Atlas Search functionality to do a `nGram Search` out of the box. From the phrasing it looks like you are self hosted and hence in that case you will have to implement this yourself.

Here is a good article on how to implement the same using MongoDB - https://danielcorcoranssql.wordpress.com/2020/07/06/fuzzy-search-with-mongodb-n-grams/

Comment: the right way to do this is with MongoDB Atlas Search, not the database

Comment: Yes absolutely. But for that, as mentioned in the answer, you have to be deployed on Atlas :/

Comment: You're right. But remember, Atlas is free

Comment: Only for shared clusters. After that it gets pretty extensive pretty quickly.